# Integral of limit $\int_{0}^{1} \lim_{n\to \infty} nz^{(n-1)} \text{d}z$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, limits

I am trying to solve the integral, but I don't know what to do when have limit inside.
I tried writing the $nz^{(n-1)}$ as exponential form, but seems not useful

This is problem 3.1.3 in Complex variables: Introduction and Application Edition 2

Comment: Can you evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{2^n}$?

Comment: Can you clarify what the region of integration is? I assume $z$ is a complex variable, in which case the notation $\int_0^1\dots\,dz$ isn't appropriate.

Comment: Evaluate the limit for all the values of $z\in[0,1]$ and see what you get.

Comment: Limit $=0$ for $z\lt 1$.  As stated the integral $=0$.